# NS 2.35 segmentation fault (core dumped) when running MDART protocol

Tags: tcl, ubuntu-20.04, ns2

When I run MDART routing protocol tcl script in NS 2.35, it says:

```
 When configured, ns found the right version of tclsh in /usr/bin/tclsh8.6
but it doesn't seem to be there anymore, so ns will fall back on running the first tclsh in your path. The wrong version of tclsh may break the test suites. Reconfigure and rebuild ns if this is a problem. 

num_nodes is set 16

INITIALIZE THE LIST xListHead

channel.cc:sendUp - Calc highestAntennaZ_ and distCST_
highestAntennaZ_ = 1.5,  distCST_ = 179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.0

SORTING LISTS ...DONE!

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

And the simulation end time supposely end at 205s but when run the animation, the simulation end at 8s. Why is that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ns found the right version of tclsh in /usr/bin/tclsh8.6
> but it doesn't seem to be there anymore

tcl8.6 : You are supposed to use the "ns-2.35 `tcl8.5.10`" : It doesn't change version or location. (Unless you move ns-allinone-2.35). The external tcl8.6 can change with e.g. an update. And later versions tend to be missing some files, e.g. in Debian / Ubuntu.

Example https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing

```
$ tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz     ## 2014 - 2017 update
$ cd ns-allinone-2.35/
$ export CC=gcc-4.8 CXX=g++-4.8 && ./install
```

---

> Segmentation fault

MDART cannot be used with a contemporary OS. The latest that worked was an Ubuntu 18.04.4 updated 16 months ago. Please see my tests https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1si2jA3lc-23lubVHb3tFbIAXfnhRfg5O?usp=sharing ..... CentOS 8 fails, Ubuntu 20.04 fails. Etc. "2021 OS" fails.

EDIT : Further tests revealed that an updated Ubuntu 18.04 failed : The latest Ubuntu version for MDART is 16.04 .

NOTE 1: The Ubuntu 16.04 `nam` package is corrupt. Please use https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNdmxzSmRzaVRWb28/view?usp=sharing →  nam_1.15-10-ubuntu14_amd64.deb

NOTE 2: The  Ubuntu 16.04 `ns` command : `sudo apt install ns2`

NOTE 3: Building ns-allinone-2.35/ → Four cases of random Tk errors after the latest Ubuntu updates. Possible solutions: Use `ns-allinone-2.35_2021.tar.xz` https://drive.google.com/file/d/167cP7hPnJGiNL3rK4Mxnh_-0t7_S8FTL/view?usp=sharing with Tcl, Tk updated to version 8.5.17 .... And there are three options for extra gcc/g++ compilers to try out https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xVEATaYAwqvseBzYxKDzJoZ4-Hc_XOJm?usp=sharing

```
export CC=gcc447 CXX=g++447 && ./install     ## can also be used with ns-allinone-2.35 version 2011
export CC=gcc48 CXX=g++48 && ./install
export CC=gcc54 CXX=g++54 && ./install
```

---

Simulation time : The setting is maximum time. Example : The setting `set val(end)  1006.0` will run about 6 seconds and end the output text with : `1000 simulation seconds` ....... Time is relative. ns2 was developed in the 90th when processors were very slow Pentium 1 / Pentium 2 . ... And different protocols behave different with simulation time.

Comment: Very helpful... Thank you for your response... been looking for the answer for months... Once again thank you

Comment: Excuse me, im having a problem on installing ns2.35 in Ubuntu 18.04.4... I already tried the command that you had provided for me. But when I run the tcl file, it still says the same thing. Did I install it wrong?
The first step that I did is extracting the ns2.35 allinone. Then, I wrote the following command:
$] sudo apt install build-essential autoconf automake libxmu-dev
$] sudo apt install gcc-4.8 g++-4.8
$ cd ns-allinone-2.35/
$ export CC=gcc-4.8 CXX=g++-4.8 && ./install

Is it wrong?

Comment: Yes, it came out as segmentation fault, The OS I installed says that last update is 2018-04-26. So it means that I need to find much older OS and update the software of ubuntu 18.04.4 to run the tcl properly?

Comment: Do I need to allow the content of software updater to be downloaded when it pop-up?

Comment: Noted. Will try.

Comment: The nam file run smoothly... Thank you sir :D